# ¿Es posible crear una API sin un Endpoint?

Tags: api

Esta duda surgió en el trabajo, según lo que he leído y la interpretación del concepto de API no es posible tener una API sin un Endpoint, sin embargo al buscar no encuentro una documentación que lo diga explicitamente.

Alguno me puede guiar, ilustrar o compartir la documentación con la cual pueda probar que efectivamente no es posible crear una API sin Endpoint

Hablo de API en general, sin distinguir entre los diferentes tipos o protocolos.

Comment: ¿Qué entiendes por ***API***? Y además, ¿qué entiendes por ***Endpoint***? Con tus palabras (sin *copy/paste* de Wikipedia)

Comment: Pues pregunto lo mismo que @MauricioContreras, para ti, ¿qué es un endpoint? ¿qué es una API? Un *endpoint* es un concepto simplemente, es parte de una URL, así sea el directorio raíz de la API. Si no hay *endpoint* conceptualmente hablando el *endpoint* sería ese directorio raíz. El hecho es que tiene que haber una fuente a la que acudir para pedir los datos a la API.

Comment: Que pena responder tarde. para mi API es una interface, que permite a un software comunicarse con otro, y el medio por el cual se comunican es ese Endpoint.
Pero la duda surge debido a que lanzar un evento o un ejecutable desde un software hacia otro podría considerarse una API, según ese concepto que les dí, sin embargo para mi no lo es, puesto que deben existir otras características, ejemplo una URL, IP o socket, etc, y no se que otras.